# How to make powershell function with input parameters globally available

Tags: powershell

I have some powershell scripts that I want to consolidate and make more useful to the developers on my project. There is now at least 3 scripts in use:

1. Clean a folder (remove a bunch of different tmp files and folders
   and restore some packages)
2. Run some functions to add EF migrations and update the database
3. Generate some basic code files based on a entityname

I want the developer to be able to write this in the ps console, example of the 3 above:

```
1. mycommand clean -solution document
2. mycommand dbupdate -solution portal
3. mycommand new -solution casework -entityname Person
```

The commands should have "autocomplete". I'm struggeling to get this to work with ps profile? Or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Have a read up on [powershell modules](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/an-introduction-to-powershell-modules/) as they will enable you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

one way is distribute the powershell module with GPO - nice guides in following [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/800085/installing-powershell-modules-through-gpo)

second way is add the cmdlets to PS Profile located in $Profile although personally I would go this way if only I would use those cmdlets. The issue is that every person will have to modify the script in their profiles if some change is need to be done.